SSO login using okta
Has anyone been successful in running Playwright using BDD in windows machine especially for an app where login is using Okta (with SSO enabled)? The challenge is script never gets the login screen. Either it uses current windows login to login and either it succeeds or fails. Especially when we have multiple user roles to test we need the login screen to come up.
Which browser are you using? I think/guess the fully open source ones might not have windows integrated authentication built-in so those might be more likely to work for you?
This might contain some useful hints:
Prevent SSO with Playwright
I try with this but it's not work
